# Tutankhamun's body

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. A group of former leftists briefly detained by firm far-rightist (7)
5. Arguments of Delaware motel owner (7)
9. Autoimmune qualities partially being one-sided (7)
10. Archangels not put up after opening of postal packages (7)
11. Adele swayed into taking off top with small cuts (9)
13. Aristocratic components in Chinese literature (5)
14. A note: Country as a whole is behind Nevada city's second naming as candidate? (12)
19. A Dutchman is perhaps master water barrier builder (12)
23. A counter charge following historic leader to capital (5)
24. Artful boy's name contains N? Certainly not (2,2,5)
27. A soldier returned in amazingly overt thriller (7)
28. About information technology: "Write badly to be more clever" (7)
29. Anarchic desire leading to short lives (7)
30. Asylum seeker, missing last odds, feels urge to go bananas (7)

**Down**
1. A company's creators discovered the southern part of Algiers (8)
2. Amsterdam-based group is behind Dutch company's bombing (8)
3. American's one night in France (5)
4. After striking its leader, ocelot devastated IT company (5)
5. At sea, troops die for investor (9)
6. A city in Spain or balance shifted? (9)
7. Article by 8 down shortly leads to dissertation (6)
8. Actively resist a woman in a convent? (6)
12. African former head of state in hiding (3)
15. A French champagne, uncorked a few times – dignified like Tutankhamun's body (9)
16. A student's writing materials, perhaps, are not electronic publications (9)
17. A Republican VP candidate in picture, almost without a stabbing (8)
18. Ahead of backup force, quietly keep safe (8)
20. Arduous piece, or a couple (3)
21. A portion of sailors have rusty razor (6)
22. A metal god captivates (6)
25. Attributes of pipeline were more recent (5)
26. A central theme of film's ending: devoted heart and healthy back (5)

Comment: All clues start with "A" - that's creative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Across:

> 1a. CIS in FAST.
>  5a. DE + BATES.
>  9a. substring.
>  10a. ARC(-hang)ELS after P(-ostal).
>  11a. (ADELE + INTO*) -A + S.
>  13a. substring.
>  14a. RENO + MI + NATION.
>  19a. MASTER* + DAMMER.
>  23a. A ION< following H.
>  24a. N in BOYSNAME*.
>  27a. GI< in OVERT*.
>  28a. WRITE* around IT.
>  29a. DESIRE* + S.
>  30a. (FEELS URGE - L(-a)S(-t))*.

Down:

> 1d. FOUND + (-algi)ERS.
>  2d. ING behind SHELL.
>  3d. I+NUIT.
>  4d. (-o)CELOT*.
>  5d. (TROOPS DIE)*.
>  6d. (OR BALANCE)*.
>  7d. THE + SIS.
>  8d. RESIST*.
>  12d. substring.
>  15d. MUMM + (-dign)IFIED.
>  16d. NOT EBOOKS.
>  17d. PALIN in IM(-a)G(-e).
>  18d. P + RESERVE.
>  20d. substring.
>  21d. substring.
>  22d. SN (tin) + ARES.
>  25d. substring.
>  26d. (-fil)M + (-dev)O(-ted) + FIT<.

I am looking forward to #17 and #24 in the series of which this is presumably #1.

Comment: +1 for the solve, but mainly because I just got your closing remark!

Comment: Hah, I get it now. Now to retreat to the study for six months...